# Need help understading sending bytes to serial port

Tags: c#, io, hex

I am building this C# application which should turn a relay. It has a USB to serial port.
The manual says:

> Module can receive single byte from upper monitor ( baud rate 9600)：

```
Upper Monitor                   0x50            0x51
ICSE012A                                0xAB
ICSE013A                                0xAD (This is the one i have)
ICSE014A                                0xAC
```

Module will turn to normal work state after receive `0x51`. Then every data byte will control the relay directly . Each bit controls a relay ( `0` mark start , `1` mark stop ) . Read following for details:

```
Bit: 0 // Controls relay 1
Bit: 1 // Controls relay 2
```

So to start the relay I should use: `This.SerialPort1.Write(0x51)`

But then I want to start relay one what do I put in? How do I understand this?

Comment: `0x51` is hex, that converts to binary as `01010001` which probably means turn on relays 1, 5 and 7. so to start only relay 1, just send binary `00000001` (hex `0x01`)

Comment: I have this software which came with the relayboard. In the software i need to open the connection and click "open the sele" and close the program before 0x01. The software must activate the board somehow.

Answer (score 4):

I have similar item ICSE013A :

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
/dev/serial/by-path/platform-20980000.usb-usb-0\:1.3\:1.0-port0
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Prolific_Technology_Inc._USB-Serial_Controller-if00-port0
/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/pl2303/ttyUSB1
```

But I think I have met a bug, or design flaw.

Unplug and replug the device.

In first console, run a permanent:

```
$ cat /dev/ttyUSB1
```

In a second console, run

```
$ echo -e -n "\x50" > /dev/ttyUSB1
```

Run it several times; each time you will receive an ack in the first console (ab, ac, or ad). Now send the start command:

```
echo '51' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

You don't get any ack. Send the same line a second time:

```
echo '51' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

switch 1 comes ON, without ack. Send 50, switch goes OFF, without ack:

```
echo '50' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

So, order of commands matter a lot. Once you have sent 50-51, all bytes will control relays. For a running script at a random time, there is no way to know if the device have been already initiated or not. One solution could be to run initiation at boot time in /etc/rc.local: but imagine you have a glitch on the USB power supply: you think you can control the relays, when actually, they are waiting for init. The relay has poor design. It's the cheapest I could find: 4e for 2 relays, 9e for a 8r board. Other USB-relays are much more expensive, but have a logic which is resistant to initialisation issues: they need to receive complete frames including checksums ... for each relay command. Things like 'A0 01 01 A2' or '01 05 00 00 FF 00 8C 3A'.

Also, grouping orders in a single frame will fail. If after powercycle you do

```
echo '50 51 03' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

it will NOT put relays ON. You have to send bytes one by one; a simple sleep 0.001 (using the bash internal command) seems enough. Behaviour may vary with shell version and kernel and distribution:

```
i=0.001
echo '50' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1 ; sleep $i
echo '51' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1 ; sleep $i
echo '03' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

Now, send this command:

```
echo '50 51 03' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

it will put relays off, without providing ack. So, how to reset the boad for sure ? From software, this seems complicated; depending on hardware, a reboot may not reset all USB devices. Reloading pl2303 is not enough. On normal desktop, unloading the whole USB stack down to usbcore should allow to reset the device. On the rPi, usbcore is not modular, and unloading usbserial is not suffisant.

So, in the case of my rPi, I have to do this at boot in /etc/rc.local

```
echo '50' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
echo '51' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

and assume the device will not be disconnected

Also: not possible to know the state of relays; when you want to change one relay, you need to remember (store) somewhere the state of other relays. Even if this aspect is managed by a daemon service, if you hot-restart the service, the service can not know if the board had been initialised or not; in doubt, the service will have to do it, and send 50-51-00 with apropriate small sleeps in between; but, in the case it had already been initialised, this may activate relays 1, 5 and 7 for a small time.

Ddifferent approach: my board has a serial port input (4 empty holes on the left of the USB plug). I soldered a few pins, and linked it to a USB-serial adapter (Rx and Tx marking are inverted). Things behaved exactly the same.

After hours of dychotomy, I have found a string that can handle initialisation, and still be used after boot. With this approach, OFF relays are untouched; ON relays are disconnected during 8ms (do not try to add a capacitor, it may produce oscilations). Depending on how the controlled device is sensible to disconnections, this small off-time may be acceptable (or not):

```
echo '50 00 50 00 51 01 00 ZZ' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

where ZZ is the relay control byte. Here is an alternative template that also works:

```
echo '50 50 50 50 51 52 00 ZZ' | xxd -r -p >>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

Edit: after a few hours of testing this card, the hardware board is not reliable. This simple test fails: every 10 or 20s, relays are left in OFF state:

```
while true ; do echo -e -n "\x03" > /dev/ttyUSB1 ; sleep 1 ; done
```

It's very slow, and still triggers a race issue inside the firmware ... And this test fails both via the onboard USB plug, and using a third party serial port adapter. There is nothing good in ICSE013A

Answer (score 1):

I have tried following commands on ubuntu successfully.
Open 2 terminals and type $ su  to get root access or alternatively you can change permissions of device by

```
$chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

*On my machine,

lsusb output: Bus 003 Device 018: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port

dmesg output : [11837.715851] usb 3-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0*

**1. On first terminal**
Type following to read the deivce id:

```
$cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | hexdump -C
```

**2.On second terminal**
Type following command to get the device ID (mine is 0xAB, 4 channel)

```
$ echo -e -n "\x50" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**3.Remove the device and check the output at first terminal**

```
$cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | hexdump -C  
00000000  ab                                                |.|    
00000001
```

**4. On second terminal**  Follow sequence of commands:
To handshake:

```
$ echo -e -n "\x50" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To activate relay controller:

```
$ echo -e -n "\x51" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To turn off all relays:

```
$ echo -e -n "\xff" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To turn on all relays:

```
$ echo -e -n "\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To turn on first relay:

```
$ echo -e -n "\x01" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To turn on fourth relay:

```
$ echo -e -n "\x04" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: correct misprint from "off" to "on"  in  $ echo -e -n "\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
$ echo -e -n "\x04" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

turns on the third relay. It's one bit per relay, we have to think in binary. So, to turn on the fourth relay, one would need to change the 4th bit, like:

```
$ echo -e -n "\x08" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as [@benoit-pierre-demaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7017803/benoit-pierre-demaine) but I came up with a different approach to solve the problem.

Since the state cannot be determined from a program therefore I decided to initialize the device from the operating system and assume that it has been initialized when I start using the device from the application.

I've created a new udev rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/ICSE014A.rules` with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/icse014a-init"
```

And I wrote a small script to initialize the device when it was plugged in with a script at `/usr/local/bin/icse014a-init`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '50' | xxd -r -p > ${DEVNAME}
sleep 1

echo '51' | xxd -r -p > ${DEVNAME}
```